# redux store is being updated but changes not being shown on some screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am updating a user profile in the redux store through some text input. The user information is visible on three screens.

1. On a userDetail screen which uses useSelector to find the user from a list of users using an Id. Here the screen reflects the changes made to the redux store.
2. On a userSummary screen. This screen shows the user details to the user where the user can then click an edit button and go to screen (3) where there are text inputs and the user can edit their details.
3. on the EditDetails screen. This is where there are the text inputs. The user can edit the details and the store in redux is updated.

However after saving the changes, and being navigated back to the previous screen (2) using `props.navigation.goBack();` screen 2 does not reflect the changes I just made to the redux store. If i go to screen (1), I can see the changes which were made. Similarly when i go to reedit the details on screen (3) the changes that were made in the first edit are showing. It's just screen (2) which does not show any changes which were made.

I get the current user using `const currentUser = useSelector(state => state.users.currentUser);` on all screens and from there I access the user child properties such as name, address, bio etc.

My initial state for my users reducer is

```
const initialState = {
    availableUsers: USERS,
    currentUser: USERS.find(user => user.id === 'b1')
};
```

I haven't connected it to a server yet so I'm just using a dummy user as the currently logged in user.

Below is my logic for updating a user's information in my user.js reducer.

```
case UPDATE_USER:
    const serveMale = action.updateInfo.male;
    const serveFemale = action.updateInfo.female;
    const newDescription = action.updateInfo.description;
    state.currentUser.Male = serveMale;
    state.currentUser.Female = serveFemale;
    state.currentUser.description = newDescription

    return {
        ...state
    }
```

I've quadruple checked in the debugger that my store is updating correctly and that is clearly shown in my screen (1) which shows the correctly updated information. Its just screen (2) which is giving me issues.

**UPDATE:**

I finally got it working. I think the issue was I was only updating the currentUser in the initialState but not the currentUser in the whole USERS array. I don't know why this worked but it did. Here is the code.

First I found the index of the current user in the array of all users.
Then made a newUser class merging the old and new information.
Then overwrite the `currentUser` and the `availableUsers[userIndex]` with the new user made and return the state.

```
case UPDATE_USER:
    const userIndex = state.availableUsers.findIndex(user === user.id === action.id);

    const serveMale = action.updateInfo.male;
    const serveFemale = action.updateInfo.female;
    const newDescription = action.updateInfo.description;

    const newUser = new User(
        state.currentUser.id,
        state.currentUser.name,
        state.currentUser.workId,
        state.currentUser.years,
        state.currentUser.imageUrl,
        serveMale,
        serveFemale,
        newDescription,
    )
    state.availableUsers[userIndex] = newUser;
    state.currentUser = newUser;
    return {
        ...state                
    }
```

Comment: are you using routing?

Comment: Maybe its because you are using another action in your screen 2 and  it clears current state in screen2 but in your screen 1 you have the right action and reducer

Answer (score 1):

In the reducer, you are mutating the state also. But not sure if this can be the reason behind the problem.

the updation should be like:

`
case UPDATE_USER:
    const { male, female, description } = action.updateInfo;

```
return {
    ...state,
    currentUser: {
      male,
      female,
      description
    }
}
```

`

Writing `state.currentUser.Male = serveMale` is actually mutating the actual state object even though u r returning a new one.

Comment: Doing what you suggested actually deleted all the other child elements of currentUser except for male, female and description. Do you know how to save the unchanged children and only overwrite the male, female and description

Comment: Write it as:


`
return {
    ...state,
    currentUser: {
     ...state.currentUser,
      male,
      female,
      description
    }
}

`

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you're using `props.navigation.goBack()` which only points you back to the point in session history where the stored information does not contain anything about your changes. Try using the `pushState()` or `push()` (if you're using React Router) to navigate after updating your store.